# Using custom names with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm using Mislav's `will_paginate` and I want to use the render option as shown in the [repository's docs](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki):

```
<%= page_entries_info @posts %>  #-> Displaying posts 6 - 10 of 26 in total
```

My particular model is named `CoPosts`, which is not as friendly as `Post`. I would love to use their render option but I would like to change `Displaying co_posts 6-10` to `Displaying posts 6-10`...

How can I change the name will_paginate uses for its rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
<%= page_entries_info @co_posts, :entry_name => 'post' %>
```

You can find more information on what options are available on the [ViewHelpers rdoc page](http://rubydoc.info/gems/will_paginate/2.3.15/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers).

An alternative to will_paginate which you might also consider is [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). It was recently covered in [RailsCast 254](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari)

Good luck with your project.

Comment: NOTE:  **:entry_name** has been changed to **:model** as of will_paginate 3.02 [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136835/entry-name-does-not-change-for-will-paginate-not-working)