# :entry_name does not change for will_paginate; not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

Does anyone know why the entry name isn't changing to what I want?

```
<div class="digg_pagination">
  <div class="page_info">
    <%= page_entries_info @user_prices, :entry_name => 'Price', :plural_name => 'Prices' %>
  </div>
    <%= will_paginate @user_prices, :container => false %>
</div>
```

I already tried getting rid of the `:plural_name` option but that didn't work either. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like its just a bug for will paginate so I just went into the translation file itself and did the following:

**config/en.yml**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user_price:
        zero:  Prices
        one:   Price
        few:   Prices
        other: Prices
```

Answer (score 12):

At some point the `:entry_name` option in `page_entries_info` has changed to `:model`.

So you can now do (in 3.0.2 at least):

```
<%= page_entries_info @user_prices, :model => 'Price' %>
```